In python, how to iterate the output of script of list of sets
In python while running a script, the output is :
[SecretElement(environment='dev', secret_comment='', secret_key='abc', secret_value='abcs'),SecretElement(environment='dev', secret_comment='', secret_key='ab1c', secret_value='abc1s')]

Here what is the data type inside the list?.
How to get the secret_key of each SecretElement in the list?
I can get each of the elements in list with a for loop.
what is the data type SecretElement?. is it set?.
How to get "secret_key" in each SecretElement?

where does this list comes from ?

Regarding the output, it seems SecretElement is a class itself
So you can just iterate over it and access it's attribute secret_key
items = []
for item in items:
    print(item.secret_key)

